# Bash script check if process is running

Tags: bash, shell, debian, bittorrent

I'm trying to write a script for deluged on my ssh server, but I'm having a hard time checking if a process is always running. It always thinks deluged is running. I have a deny all iptable setup, and don't really know how to make it work unless I set up these rules every time I run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#starts deluged and deluge console
echo "Start or Close Deluge?"
read startcls
if [[ $startcls == "S" || $startcls == "s" ]]; then
    if [ -z "$(pgrep deluged)" ]; then
        echo "Deluge Daemon already running. Close it?"
        read input
        if [[ $input == "y" || $input == "Y" ]]; then
            pkill  deluged
            iptables -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 57714 -j ACCEPT
            iptables -P INPUT DROP
            echo "Deluged process terminated"
        fi
    else
        iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 57714 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
        deluged
        echo "Deluge Daemon started"
        deluge-console
    fi
else
    pkill deluged
    iptables -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 57714 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -P INPUT DROP
    echo "Deluged process terminated"
fi
```

Comment: `[ -z "$(pgrep deluged)" ]` is going return true when no `deluged` processes are running. What else about this isn't working specifically? And what was the question about `iptables` exactly?

Comment: woops i switched it around. thx. I have my iptables set up to drop all connections incoming and outgoing unless they are related to my SSH daemon. I can't use deluge because of this, and I'm not sure what ports are needed for it to work. I'd rather not accept all input while using deluge and only open the necessary ports. I know i need port 57714 to use the cli interface, but idk what ports i should open to actually download torrents.

Comment: You should be able to set a range in deluge for what ports it opens for connections I would imagine. I know other clients can do that.

Answer (score 0):

may be your script name has the word "deluged" in it.  Change it to something like Deluge_check.sh (with a uppercase 'D')